# unexpected EOF, missing quote or backtick?

Tags: linux, bash, curl, debian

I'm working on a script that in use with other scripts can send system or other notifications  through [Telegram](https://telegram.org/), the script pulls the data from [domoticz](http://www.domoticz.com).

I'm sure i'm missing a quote or backtick somewhere but i hope someone is kind enough to read over the small script and provide a fresh pair of eyes to see where i messed up:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Settings
TelegramSendMsg="/opt/telegram/scripts/generic/telegram.sh"
TmpFileName="/opt/telegram/scripts/tmp/SystemStatus.txt"
SendMsgTo=$1

#Send sensor values with telegram
##############################################################################
ResultString+="CPU Usage: "
ResultString+=`curl "http://192.168.1.141:8086/json.htm?type=devices&rid=8" 2>/dev/null` | jq -r .result[].Data`
ResultString+="\n"

ResultString+="Memory Usage: "
ResultString+=`curl "http://192.168.1.141:8086/json.htm?type=devices&rid=1" 2>/dev/null | jq -r .result[].Data`
ResultString+="\n"

ResultString+=`curl "http://192.168.1.141:8086/json.htm?type=devices&rid=6" 2>/dev/null | jq -r .result[].Name`
ResultString+=" : "
ResultString+=`curl "http://192.168.1.141:8086/json.htm?type=devices&rid=6" 2>/dev/null | jq -r .result[].Data`
ResultString+="\n"

ResultString+=`curl "http://192.168.1.141:8086/json.htm?type=devices&rid=4" 2>/dev/null | jq -r .result[].Name`
ResultString+=" : "
ResultString+=`curl "http://192.168.1.141:8086/json.htm?type=devices&rid=4" 2>/dev/null | jq -r .result[].Data`
ResultString+="\n"

ResultString+=`curl "http://192.168.1.141:8086/json.htm?type=devices&rid=5" 2>/dev/null | jq -r .result[].Name`
ResultString+=" : "
ResultString+=`curl "http://192.168.1.141:8086/json.htm?type=devices&rid=5" 2>/dev/null | jq -r .result[].Data`
ResultString+="\n"

ResultString+=`curl "http://192.168.1.141:8086/json.htm?type=devices&rid=3" 2>/dev/null | jq -r .result[].Name`
ResultString+=" : "
ResultString+=`curl "http://192.168.1.141:8086/json.htm?type=devices&rid=3" 2>/dev/null | jq -r .result[].Data`
ResultString+="\n"

ResultString+=`curl "http://192.168.1.141:8086/json.htm?type=devices&rid=2" 2>/dev/null | jq -r .result[].Name`
ResultString+=" : "
ResultString+=`curl "http://192.168.1.141:8086/json.htm?type=devices&rid=2" 2>/dev/null | jq -r .result[].Data`
ResultString+="\n"

##############################################################################
echo -e $ResultString > $TmpFileName
$TelegramSendMsg send_text $SendMsgTo $TmpFileName
```

Comment: Please read [Why is $(...) preferred over `...` (backticks)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stackoverflow's syntax highlite tells that something wrong here

```
ResultString+=`curl "http://192.168.1.141:8086/json.htm?type=devices&rid=8" 2>/dev/null` | jq -r .result[].Data`
```

It is backtick here

```
null`
```

Comment: indeed, just as you said the syntax higlighter lit up that line I saw the error... stupid, stupid, stupid. It now works perfectly. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to be the tick next to null on line 11